# Without session id, how to find the content url of application. I only know the application name

Tags: vespa

If I know only the application name, want to have a look at its schema, what can I do?

In other words, how to get the conent url of application by application name?

Comment: The schema files are in the application package which is deployed to Vespa. Are you using Vespa Cloud or doing self-hosting? in Vespa Cloud, you will find application endpoints in the Vespa Console.

Comment: self-hosting.  The way from annswer below is feasible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like this is not documented, but you can get content without session id by doing e.g. http://07f98dce1fa0:19071/application/v2/tenant/default/application/default/environment/prod/region/default/instance/default/content/schemas/music.sd

Comment: This works well. Thanks.  Yes it is not documented.